# foreach error with EntityCollection<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Hello I am getting an error i can't explain it.

I am trying to parse an EntityCollection with a foreach loop

Here is the error I get :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<MyEntity>'
>   because
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<MyEntity>'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

This is really strange because I had a console application and i was working very well. BUt then I wanted to make a web application.

With the console app, i can perform the foreach, but I get the error in the Web application.

This is driving me crazy. please help :)

Here is the code:

```
foreach (INITIATIVE_REF_STRATEGIC_AXIS stratAxe in i.INITIATIVE_REF_STRATEGIC_AXIS)
{

}
```

`i.INITIATIVE_REF_STRATEGIC_AXIS` is of type `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<INITIATIVE_REF_STRATEGIC_AXIS>`

Comment: Try calling `ToList` like this: `foreach(var item in collection.ToList())`

Comment: Same kind of error here :
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext ()) I Get this error : 
type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

When MyContext inherits from ObjectContext that Inherits from IDisposable ...

Comment: why not just show your code like everyone else?

Comment: Thanks for help Jens. I did , but the code inside is underlined with green color : "code unreachable"

Comment: try showing your `MyContext` class and the `foreach` loop

Comment: `EntityCollection<TEntity>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so it is iterable with a foreach.  Are you sure you having all your using stements...possible namespace conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linq Extension Methods are not in the context, thats why you are getting this error.

1) Verify if the project has the reference for:

```
System.Data.Entity.dll
```

2) If you are using ASP.NET MVC put this at the top of the View

```
@using System.Linq;
```

Or in the web.config in the views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Hopes this help you!

Comment: Thanks for help, in fact i did add System.Data.Entity.dll.

As I said above, it was a compiler error, gone after 1st build.

Comment: :) No problem! Just give me a tickup!

Comment: Hey In fact that was that !

Give me a tick up too so i get 15 reputation and i will be able to vote up.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you are missing an assembly reference.

Your code is giving compile errors and it hasn't yet gone and refreshed all the references properly. Hence why it can;t see stuff that you know is there.

its a bit of a pig ... go delete all your bin directories clean and rebuild all and cross fingers.

failing that start removing references from projects and reading them.

usually fixes eventually.

You probably have another build error in your output ... fixing that will probably let an assembly compile that will then allow something else to compile that will fix your problem here.

If you sort your build errors by the number column and fix the lowest number first you may find things easier.

Comment: This helped me, in fact thanks a lot !! Error gone with a simple build ... It was just the compiler that was lost. Thanks

I'd vote for your answer with more reputation ...